# Can I use a dual high-side low-side gate driver as a dual low-side driver?

Tags: mosfet, driver, gate-driving

Some background: I am building a 350 VA DC to AC inverter, partly for my own curiosity, but mostly for a senior design project for my bachelor's.

What I have with me is monolithic dual high-and-low drivers with a 4A peak current driver, shown [here.](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/200/irs2186pbf-34252.pdf) My planned first stage is going to be a push-pull type half bridge through the center tap of a transformer I hijacked out of an off-the shelf-UPS. I'll be doing this as mod-square wave, because the transformer is mains frequency rated, and I don't have time to get anything different. That output will then get rectified, stored, and h-bridged with my real experiment, which should be a low distortion sine wave output.

The push-pull mod-square arrangement doesn't need a high side driver, on account of not having one to speak of.

So, my question:

Given what I have available, can I use the high side output of the gate driver as a low-side output? I look at it, and it seems I would just have to omit the bootstrap capacitor and diode, connect Vb to Vcc, and connect Vs to GND, and then (I believe) it should work.

I have some time, but I have limited resources and I really just wanted to know before I go and etch a board. I also don't have a bunch of MOSFETs lying around to blow up while I learn. Also, using a single IC would save me some board space, and the chips have internally matched propagation delays.

I would appreciate any feedback on this application, or anything else the community would like to share.

Comment: It should work but for the sake of $3 why not get a proper one - after all it's for your degree! Alternatively use two and forget about the topside drivers. Surely risk must be a factor for something as important as this?

Comment: If this were a prototype for manufacturing, definitely would get a native dual low side. Still might. The propagation delay between two drivers could be as much as 80 nanoseconds compared to the built in 35 ns max. Not really an issue at this frequency. But I'm holding several of these drivers in my possession right now. Surely the ability to use common components for multiple functions adds value? And it has nice volume price breaks. I'm open to any and all opinions.

Comment: Including the distinct possibility that I should just shut up and get a different part.

Comment: I didn't see it in the IR spec but does the device provide "blanking" so there is a distinct gap of 20-50ns between one FET turning off and the other turning on? Also, why aren't you considering using a buck regulator to provide the centre-tap dc voltage then using the MOSFETs to switch high and low to the transformer?

Comment: Because I'm just that kind of a silly person. Honestly it hadn't actually occurred to me. And I'm not sure I'm personally capable of reasonably controlling the duty cycle under loaded conditions. I've proven to be rather bad at feedback loops but I'll get right on it. On the blanking thing, I'm pretty sure its just up to me to not do something stupid with the independent inputs. The terminals aren't inverting or anything, its just two different logic drive inputs that have been built so that signals propagate at close to the same rate.

Comment: If your talking yourself out of using a buck regulator, don't. You can make a sync buck regulator using your existing chip and these are easy to control because the duty cycle x input voltage equals output voltage. Just add an LC low pass filter ans it's job done. Google it and see what I mean. The only loading effect is due to non-zero on resistance of the push-pull mosfets. I've just done a 200 watt one using a 555 timer switching at 100kHz. Easy, worked first time.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to compensate for voltage input change? Or did you just force the 555 reset pin low at the limit? Or play with the control pin maybe?

Comment: yes you would BUT that doesn't involve a feedback loop - if v doubles you halve the duty cycle and that ain't too hard and no chance of instability.

Comment: I used 555 as a  sawtooth generator feeding a comparator. The comparator output duty cycle was controlled by the dc demand voltage on the other input. This input was reduced or increased as supply voltage increased or decreased above a nominal set point

Comment: See, that is the kind of simple elegance I am not hardwired for. Thank you for that. What flavor comparator did you use?

Comment: for the production model I'm going to use an LTC6992. Check it out. It's a single chip that takes a 0 to 1 volt analogue input and produces PWM at a frequency defined by one resistor.

Comment: Mind you I'm still shy of that bachelor's. So if I understand this IC correctly, it is internally generating the sawtooth wave to make it's duty cycle so you can now just pass the analog voltage through a resistive divider. Is that about the jist of it?

Comment: Just google it dude it's almost self explanatory.

Comment: Thanks for all this. The University of Houston doesn't actually require a student to go through power converters before they get to the senior design project, so I don't have much in the way of practical knowledge concerning this stuff, just what I've cobbled together and the kindness of strangers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you c an use both as low side drivers,although the high side is filtered to prevent shoot thru failure simultaneous switching resulting in a dead band required for totem pole switching, so no effect in  half bridge..

Edit:

I think the chip is a complementary output drive going to what I understand is to drive low side in half bridge  with center .tap to DC.  The is somewhat like a secondary diode half bridge using 2 diodes and center tap ground. So there are are VI tradeoffs when using this method, less voltage, more current..   This chip has good **deadband** filters for commutation on the high side, but you wont need this.

I would explore the tradeoffs of open-drain inductive switches vs tri-level active outputs ( full bridge ) with 0, +V , -V methods for sine inverters. Look at [***IGBT***](http://www.irf.com/technical-info/refdesigns/irsolwib.pdf) switches , which are preferred for large sine power motor controllers.

If it were my design I would use the lowest MOSFET or IGBT resistance switches that I could afford , in milliohms.
Read [***this***](http://cas.web.cern.ch/cas/Warrington/PDF/Carroll.pdf) all about Switching...Theory in semi's. then decide. It compares the old SCR, MoSFET with IGBT and newer enhanced gate types. Toshiba makes these too.

Comment: Great stuff, but I thought at these power levels IGBTs weren't really justified? Max 350 VA at 120 volt rms? And definitely, once this project is over I want to play with a multi level pure sine IGBT design.

Comment: Also, this is actually a three level inverter scheme I'm putting together.

Answer (score 0):

Following extensive discussion in comments here's what I'd do. The H-bridge you propose for the AC output stage is fine - that's the right thing to do but between your battery and that H bridge you need to control the DC level - the AC output will need to be regulated and the easiest way to do it in my book is feed the H bridge circuit with a variable level DC. For this I'd use a synchronous buck converter for the following reasons: -

- Synchronous means higher efficiency (95% as opposed to 90% for non-sync)
- Output voltage is quite simply input voltage x mark-space ratio
- Reducing mark-space when input Vsupply rises OR increasing mark-space ratio when Vsupply falls does not require feedback - it can be done using feed-forward.

[image]

You should use one of your IR drivers to control two N channel FETs that do the switching but make sure you provide a small deadband. You can do this using an AND gate and a NOR gate - feed a squarewave and a delayed-by-50 ns squarewave into both and look at the output waveforms.Delay can just be an RC network: -

[image]

Note that the OR gate shown above needs to be a NOR gate and preferably both AND and NOR should be schmitt trigger devices.

For PWM I'd use this: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting so I could upvote! I decided to accept the Joe's answer since it directly addressed the driver question, but you really straightened out my entire design. If I could upvote five times, I would.